# Trying to set up flask with nginx and gunicorn on EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: python, flask, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I have followed a simple guide, and trying to show my flask application, but it wont show. I am running everything through ssh on a EC2 ubuntu server.

Have my flask app and wsgi.py in /home/ubuntu/hike

Then here is my gunicorn application config located in: /etc/systemd/system/agriTales.service

```
[Unit]
    Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Flask
    After=network.target
    [Service]
    User=root
    Group=www-data
    WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/hike
    Environment="PATH=/env/agriTales-venv/bin"
    ExecStart=/env/agriTales-venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind /var/run/agriTales.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My nginx config is:

```
server{
            listen 80;
            server_name 54.202.87.139;
            location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass  http://unix:/var/run/agriTales.sock;
                }
            }
```

I have symlinked the file to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Have checked all processes are running, and systemd status ok, but when i try to curl

http://application
I get nothing?

My app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        mountains = ['Everest', 'K2', 'Kilimanjaro']
        return render_template('index.html', mountain=mountains)

    @app.route('/mountain/<mt>')
    def mountain(mt):
        return "This is " + str(mt)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

wsgi.py
'''
from peak import app

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

'''
What am I missing here, how to get it working?

[image: AWS inbound rules]

Comment: If the IP address is what you show in your config file, then I would suspect the firewall is blocking access. Ports 80/443 do not seem to be exposed on that IP address.